# The param was changed by passed to a function when I call the function

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, gdb

The function is defined like this:

```
1 db_bool cm_text_equal(const cm_text_t *text1, const cm_text_t *text2, db_bool case_ins)
```

and it will be called like this:

```
cm_format_element_t * cm_fetch_fmt_element(cm_text_t * fmt)
{
    db_uint32 i;
    cm_text_t   cmp_text;

    CM_POINTER(fmt);

    cmp_text.str = fmt->str;

    for(i = 0; i < DATE_FORMAT_COUNT; i++)
    {
        cmp_text.len = g_fmt_elements[i].name.len;
        if(cmp_text.len > fmt->len)
        {
            continue;
        }
        //2 the problem happens here where the function be called
        if(cm_text_equal(&g_fmt_elements[i].name, &cmp_text, DB_TRUE))
        {
           fmt->str += cmp_text.len;
           fmt->len = (db_uint16)(fmt->len - cmp_text.len);
           return &g_fmt_elements[i];
         }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

the g_fmt_elements[] is defined like this:

```
cm_format_element_t g_fmt_elements[DATE_FORMAT_COUNT] =
{
    {{1, (db_char *)" "}, FMT_SPACE_SPLIT, DB_TRUE},
    {{1, (db_char *)"-"}, FMT_MINUS_SPLIT, DB_TRUE},
   ...
}

typedef struct tagcm_format_element
{
   cm_text_t         name;
   db_uint16       id;
   db_bool         reverse_used;
}cm_format_element_t;

typedef struct tagcm_text
{
   db_uint32       len;
   db_char       * str;
}cm_text_t;
```

I debug the program by gdb. so before the function cm_text_equal called. the threee parameters are:

```
&g_fmt_elements[i].name = (cm_text_t *) 0x7f24f8766890
&cmp_text=0x7f2553ef8790
DB_TRUE=1
```

when cm_fetch_fmt_element is running to the line "//2 the problem...".
the i=30. and the variable g_fmt_elements is a global static variable.
you can see its definition below.

```
(gdb) p g_fmt_elements[30]
$57 = {name = {len = 4, str = 0x7f24f854a949 "YYYY"}, id = 226, reverse_used      = 1}
(gdb) p &g_fmt_elements[30]
$58 = (cm_format_element_t *) 0x7f24f8766890
```

Then I step into the function cm_text_equal, and it turns out:

```
(gdb) s
cm_text_equal (text1=0x7f256ec655d0, text2=0x7f2553ef8790, case_ins=1) at src/db_text.c:504
```

so you can see, the first param was changed from  0x7f24f8766890 to 0x7f256ec655d0, and I check the regesters:

```
(gdb) p/x $rdi
$52 = 0x7f256ec655d0
(gdb) p/x $rsi
$53 = 0x7f2553ef8790
(gdb) p/x $rdx
$54 = 0x1
```

you can see the first param passed into the rdi was real changed. Does anyone know how that happend?

I also checked two different addrs.

```
(gdb) p *(cm_format_element_t*)0x7f256ec655d0
$55 = {name = {len = 4, str = 0x7f256ea6275c "YYYY"}, id = 226, reverse_used = 0}
(gdb) p *(cm_format_element_t*)0x7f24f8766890
$56 = {name = {len = 4, str = 0x7f24f854a949 "YYYY"}, id = 226, reverse_used = 1}
```

you see, 0x7f24f8766890 is the right addr and its value is the same as definition. while the other addr 0x7f256ec655d0 is wrong, but I don't understand its value almost the same as the right one. However the last member is wrong, which makes my program runs abnormally.

**here is more details that I found later**

*thank you all for trying to help.
I guess I found where to be wrong.
It almost took me two days to figure out the reason, I am not good at. Haha.
but I just still want to answer it for others who may have the same problems.
Ok, let's begin.*

Because I have restart my program, so the addr have changed. so this time 
before step into the function. the add of g_fmt_elements[30] is:

```
(gdb) p g_fmt_elements[30]
$6 = {name = {len = 4, str = 0x2ae97faa554e "YYYY"}, id = 226, reverse_used   = 1}
(gdb) p &g_fmt_elements[30]
 $7 = (cm_format_element_t *) 0x2ae97fcc34d0
(gdb)
```

and after step into the function, the param text1 become to :

```
(gdb)  cm_text_equal (text1=0x2ae90be468f0, text2=0x2ae926d85540, case_ins=1) at src/db_text.c:499
```

so, you see, the (cm_format_element_t *) 0x2ae97fcc34d0 seems to changed to text1=0x2ae90be468f0, so I also check these two addr's context:

```
//-->the right one
(gdb)p *(cm_format_element_t*)0x2ae97fcc34d0 
{name = {len = 4, str = 0x2ae97faa554e "YYYY"}, id = 226, reverse_used = 1}
//-->the wrong one
(gdb)p *(cm_format_element_t*)0x2ae90be468f0 
{name = {len = 4, str = 0x2ae90bc432e6"YYYY"}, id = 226, reverse_used = 0}
```

the two's context almost same but the values of "addr of str" and "reverse_used".

so, how exactly the wrong addr 0x2ae90be468f0 comes, and why the context is almost the same?

so, info the libs addr of the program and found which lib does the addr 0x2ae90be468f0  belonged to.

Comment: @LPs, I offer the detail structure, pls look up once more, thx.

Comment: ok, I will add more details.

Comment: Try to do `cm_text_t *p = &(g_fmt_elements[i].name);` and then `if(cm_text_equal(p, &cmp_text, DB_TRUE))`. Also, I would try to disable compiler optimization, if active.

Comment: 0x00002ae90be45f20 - 0x00002ae90be45fd8 is .got in /home/byfr/lib/libldbc_util.so
 0x00002ae90be45fe8 - 0x00002ae90be46480 is .got.plt in /home/byfr/lib/libldbc_util.so   
    ---> the wrong addr ----0x00002ae90be468f0
 0x00002ae90be46480 - 0x00002ae90be46ad0 is .data in /home/byfr/lib/libldbc_util.so      
 0x00002ae90be46ae0 - 0x00002ae90be46b58 is .bss in /home/byfr/lib/libldbc_util.so

Comment: so I found it belongs to the lib of libldbc_util.so, and the lib is not my own program's lib, it's an application's lib. so I ask some to search the symbol of 
g_fmt_elements in the application's source code. Guess what? The application's
 source code have the same globle g_fmt_elements as my program's g_fmt_elements. 
And the definitions are totally same.

Comment: However, I still don't understand, when I print g_fmt_elements[30] and 
&g_fmt_elements[30], the addr and context is in my program's lib, but when the 
function cm_text_equal is called, pass the other lib's g_fmt_elements addr, how that happend?